# pig ship tar files

Tags: streaming, tar, apache-pig

I read alot of about pig can ship a tar file and untar it before execution. However, I couldn't find any example. Can someone provide an example?

What I would like to do is to ship a python module, such as nltk, for my streaming.

Thanks.
Dan